# Have two different master files compiled with AucTeX

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex, latexmk, multiple-files

I use a template for exercises where I have a `ex` environnement, and then a `sol` environnement. Theses files are included in one master file called for instance `AF1920_serie4.tex`, and in another file called `AF1920_serie4_solutions.tex`.

In both master files, I included local variables:

```latex
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

In my exercises files, I would like to have something like

```latex
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-one-master: "../Serie4/AF1920_serie4.tex", "../Serie4/AF1920_serie4_solutions.tex"
%%% End:
```

and that both files are compiled whenever I call `C-c C-c` with `latexmk` in the exercise file. Would it be possible?

I checked the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Multifile.html) but I didn't manage to do what I want.